# Deadlocks on long transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, transactions

I am using EntityFramework 6 on SQL Server 2012 and .NET 4.5.1.

During long run transactions a second user occurs deadlocks. The problem is that the first user blocks records for `PayrollListHumanResourceID=90FA9981-AFD3-43BF-AD92-AAE5E2A42B5A` and the second one wants to take data for `PayrollListHumanResourceID=6CFE74C3-F180-497C-8DDA-BCA8D075FF59`.

The below code shows a transaction from SQL Profiler for an Entity Framework client. For the second user the last (sometimes the penultimate) `exec` goes deadlock. For the sake of example I deleted most of functions that work fine. I put a breakpoint for the first user just after `DELETE` section and before `COMMIT` in C# code. The first user has different `p__linq` value.

```
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted


begin tran;
 (...)
 exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [Extent1] FROM [dbo].[PayrollListErrors] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[PayrollListHumanResourceID] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='6CFE74C3-F180-497C-8DDA-BCA8D075FF59'
 exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [Extent1] FROM [dbo].[PayrollListElementRelations] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[PayrollListHumanResourceID] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='6CFE74C3-F180-497C-8DDA-BCA8D075FF59'
 exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [Extent1] FROM [dbo].[PayrollListElements] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[PayrollListHumanResourceID] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='6CFE74C3-F180-497C-8DDA-BCA8D075FF59'

commit;
```

Below an image with table keys and indexes. [image: PayrollListElements table]

The general table built in my database is:

- ID column of type INT, with Clustered Index (now obsolete, for human-friendly reading),
- GUID column of type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, PRIMARY KEY, with Non-Clustered Index,
- Foreign keys of type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, with Non-Clustered Indexes (pointed to GUID columns of course),
- every foreign key has an index (except 2 columns used for log informations, but they are not used in this transaction).

**Lock escalation** does not appear in my example. **Changing isolation level** has no effect. Deleting/Updating this table by the `ID` column works without any deadlock:

```
DELETE [Extent1] FROM [dbo].[PayrollListElements] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].ID = 30
```

The problem arises when rows are being deleted from tables and foreign key references are being checked. When I am deleting a row from a parent table, all child references are being checked. Despite all foreign keys have a non-clustered index some of them are being checked via **index scan** instead of **index seek**. If during this operation another user blocks at least one row from the scanned table - the delete operation will be blocked. It happens even when a blocking row has no reference with deleting data. **Using the FORCESEEK Table Hint** has no effect.

[image: Delete execution plan]

[Deadlock graph.xdl](http://www.filedropper.com/deadlocks31)

[Delete execution plan.sql](http://www.filedropper.com/deleteexecutionplan)

[Trace profiler.trc](http://www.filedropper.com/trace3)

Comment: Capture the deadlock graph XML and attach it here. Read [Capturing Deadlocks in SQL Server](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/)

Comment: Remus Rusanu - I just edited my post and attached additional files, deadlock graph included.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have correctly identified the scans as the problem. The scans are run under effective serializable isolation so that no new rows can appear right after the check and violate the FK.

Even if it was possible to force these checks to use nested loops I would advise against that. This seems like a fairly brittle and manual fix. In fact I don't think it would be a complete fix; It would just reduce the likelihood of a deadlock. Even if the checks find no applicable rows range key locks will still be taken on the *previous* key. You can't avoid overlap.

The best idea that I have so far is to implement the most general solution to deadlocks possible: A retry loop that retries on `SqlException.Number == 1205`. You must retry the entire transaction. This always works and is safe.

An alternative would be to use something like a global lock to not run potentially conflicting operations at the same time. That's the nuclear option and a weapon of last resort because it destroys scalability of this particular part of the system.

Comment: Yet another option would be use queue for long operations and schedule serialized queue execution (optionally using global/application locks to ensure serial behavior). This of course can be used only in cases, when user doesn't need to see processing result immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but that not solve my problem in a convenient way. Is it possible to force SQL to not use **index scan** in this example? **I removed foreign keys from the tables and have no more deadlocks.** I am not satisfied from this solution though and I can't imagine, that everybody has that problem and live with it by 'workarounds'. That would mean SQL Server does not provide any efficient solution with transactions, foreign keys and indexes in real world projects with multithreading/multiply users.

Comment: Your ultimate conclusion is a bit too far reaching... The thing that causes the scan here is that the scanned table is very small, the input happens to be already sorted and there is a properly sorted index. It's clearly the lowest cost plan. Very good efficient plan! And as I explained, a loop join would *not* resolve the issue. Do you agree?

Comment: Here is another workaround: Before performing the delete, obtain an U-lock on the FK table (WITH (UPDLOCK, TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)). That serializes write access to that table. Read access is unaffected.

Comment: It is true that complicated schemas, complicated transactions and high consistency requirements are a little prone to blocking and deadlocking. I don't think this is a SQL Server issue. It's in the nature of such systems. Sometimes, retrying on failure is a very convenient and general solution. Here, it's apparently not easily doable for you. At the same time you have hit a hard deadlock case. Most cases are easy.

Comment: Thank you usr for your involvement and please try to understand me. I have system for payroll lists calculation where one transaction lasts over 30 seconds (complex calculations) for one employee - multiply this by hundreds employees in one payroll list and dozen worksites that calculate own payroll lists on one database. Retrying after every deadlock would mean unworkable system for my clients. I just can't imagine that SQL Server throws deadlocks only because 3 tables are too small to use index seek instead of scan. I would prefere wait several seconds longer than reach deadlocks.

Comment: I understand that situation. Try the U-lock idea. Maybe you can split into two transactions: One to compute what should be done using snapshot isolation which does not take locks on data at all, and another quick one to write the data. I can't offer you a simple switch to turn this problem off. It's a hard case. Get creative and try the solutions that I posted so far.